# What is the maximum memory size of a motherboard?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer

What is the maximum memory size that the motherboard in personal computer in current market can support?

Comment: It ultimately depends on the processor, not on the motherboard (though the number of memory slots may be a limiting factor). The memory controller is built into the CPU on modern systems.

Comment: It depends on both actually.

Comment: Is it possible to build a computer with 512 GB memory with newegg.com?

Comment: If you need 512GB of memory for what you intend to do, you should look into clustered computing. You'll find even with 512GB of memory, one system cannot make efficient use of it outside of a very limited number of applications.

Comment: This motherboard here is the only one newegg sells that can support 512GB of memory. (requires 2 processors to have 512GB. 256GB split between the two) http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813182351

Comment: I donno, this changes every generation, and if you got a workstation or even a tower server, yoiu could shove *ludicious* amounts of ram in there.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It does change each generation, but even in the next couple years, it isn't likely that a single system with 512GB memory will prove better than 2-4 machines clustered with 256-128GB memory in cost or performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On older motherboards (before about 2006) this was determined by your memory controller, which was part of the North Bridge (also commonly incorrectly known as "the chipset").

Newer motherboards will have the north bridge integrated into the CPU.

Most modern (6th generation intel - Dec 2015) consumer processors can address a maximum of 64GB of memory. This isn't a hardware limitation as it once was. (64-bit is not related to 64GB memory cap either, don't let it confuse you).

The server processors intel markets can address more than 1TB of memory.

Comment: And the maximum usable memory installable on a motherboard is dependent on what the manufacturer set sit to be. Common cheap laptops may be limited to 4 or 8GB even though the above components are able to support more.